# ARM template syntax to inject an param of type object into a field who's type is also expecting an object?

Tags: azure, azure-rm-template

My aim is to dynamically inject AppSettings into my .NET applications that are hosted on Azure's App Service offering. I've got a few settings e.g. `key3` and `key4` that I would like to inject in a [copy loop](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-create-multiple) defined in a parameter named `appList` that will be available for all my apps.

I'm trying to [figure out the syntax](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-authoring-templates) to inject a defined parameter of mine named `myAppSettings` of type `object`. I've looked at Microsoft's docs regarding [using objects as parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/building-blocks/extending-templates/objects-as-parameters) but it doesn't quite fit my case.

Here is my code

**azuredeploy.json**

```
{
  "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentParameters.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "parameters": {
    "aspName": { "value": "my-asp" },
    "aspSkuName": { "value": "B1" },
    "webAppNameHostnameSuffix": { "value": "myhost.com" },
    "appList": { "value": [ "myapp1", "myapp2", "myapp3","myapp4"] }
    "myAppSettings": {
      "value": {
        "key3": "value3",
        "key4": "value4"
      }
    }    
  }
}
```

**azuredeploy.parameters.json**

```
{
  "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "parameters": {
    "aspName": { "type": "string", "minLength": 1,"metadata": { "description": "Name of App Service Plan" } },
    "aspSkuName": {"type": "string", "allowedValues": [ "F1", "D1", "B1", "B2", "B3", "S1", "S2", "S3", "P1", "P2", "P3", "P4" ] },
    "appList": { "type": "array" },
    "myAppSettings": { "type": "object" }
  },
  "variables": {},
  "resources": [
    {
      "name": "[parameters('aspName')]",
      "type": "Microsoft.Web/serverfarms",
      "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
      "apiVersion": "2015-08-01",
      "sku": { "name": "[parameters('aspSkuName')]" },
      "tags": { "displayName": "asp1" },
      "properties": {
        "name": "[parameters('aspName')]",
        "numberOfWorkers": 1
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "[concat(parameters('webAppAzureNamePrefix'), parameters('appList')[copyIndex()])]",
      "copy": {
        "name": "webAppCopy",
        "count": "[length(parameters('appList'))]"
      },
      "type": "Microsoft.Web/sites",
      "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
      "apiVersion": "2015-08-01",
      "dependsOn": [ "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/serverfarms', parameters('aspName'))]" ],
      "tags": { "displayName": "webapp" },
      "properties": {
        "name": "[concat('some-prefix', parameters('appList')[copyIndex()])]",
        "serverFarmId": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/serverfarms', parameters('aspName'))]"
      },
      "resources": [
        {
          "name": "appsettings",
          "type": "config",
          "apiVersion": "2015-08-01",
          "dependsOn": [ "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/sites', concat('some-prefix', parameters('appList')[copyIndex()]))]" ],
          "tags": { "displayName": "appsettings" },
          "properties": { [parameters('myAppSettings')] }
        },
        {
          "name": "web",
          "type": "config",
          "apiVersion": "2015-08-01",
          "dependsOn": [ "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/sites', concat('some-prefix', parameters('appList')[copyIndex()]))]" ],
          "tags": { "displayName": "web" },
          "properties": { "alwaysOn": true }
        }
      ]
    }  
  ],
  "outputs": {}
}
```

The error is being throw at the line

`"properties": { [parameters('myAppSettings')] }`

**error message**

```
[ERROR] New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment : Invalid character after parsing property name. Expected ':' but got: }. Path 
[ERROR] 'resources[1].resources[0].properties', line 62, position 57.
[ERROR] At line:3 char:1
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
"properties": "[parameters('myAppSettings')]"
```

if a variable\parameter is an object and something expects an object, just pass the variable\parameter.

same goes for arrays.

Comment: Thanks @4c74356b41, I initially tried that too but editor gave me a warning so I tried another syntax combination. Ignoring the editor warnings and directly running the `New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment` give me any trouble at all! Working great!

Comment: yeah, intellisense is bugged for arm templates. "deal with it". btw you should accept this answer if it helped you ;)

Comment: Yep, i've been learning to "deal with it" for many of the new things Azure is rolling out. I also realised [Stackoverflow enforces a delay for accepting answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/250132/why-cant-i-accept-an-answer-in-the-first-15-minutes-after-asking-the-question) :)